# Track change of user meta data in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

OK so I've managed to successfully create a few new user meta fields, which the user updates themselves with a form.

I would however like to track the progress of a user with these fields. Say the fields are 'weight' or 'bodyfat', rather than it just replacing the value it would be great if I could somehow log a value name, date and value all at once.

The dream would to then plot these values on a line chart, but thats another question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with serialization logic. Let me show you one example.

```
//read old data
$bodyfat=get_user_meta($user_id,'bodyfat',true);

//add new value
if (!is_array($bodyfat)) {$bodyfat=array();}
$bodyfat[]=$NEWVALUE;

//save new data
update_user_meta($user_id,'bodyfat',$bodyfat);
```

You can also store data by date:

```
//read old data
$bodyfat=get_user_meta($user_id,'bodyfat',true);

//add new value
if (!is_array($bodyfat)) {$bodyfat=array();}
$bodyfat[date('Y-m-d')]=$NEWVALUE;

//save new data
update_user_meta($user_id,'bodyfat',$bodyfat);
```

As you see i haven't used PHP serialize()/unserialize() functions, because get_user_meta and update_user_meta are doing it themselves.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. Does that date part get the current date? I'm really new to PHP

Comment: Yes it does it.